# Show that the set $\mathscr{B}$ is a frame of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Is it also a tight frame?

Tags: real-analysis

1. Show that the set $\mathscr{B}=\{ (\frac{1}{2},0,0,0), (\frac{1}{2},1,0,0), (\frac{1}{2},1,1,0), (\frac{1}{2},1,1,1), (0,0,0,1) \}$ is a frame of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Is it also a tight frame?
2. Find a matrix representation of the analysis, the sunthesis and frame operators.

The matrix that represents $\mathscr{B}$ is the following matrix.
$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

How to I see that this matrix is a frame?

Comment: Are you sure that $\Bbb{R}^3$ isn't supposed to be $\Bbb{R}^4$? or am I missing something.. perhaps I'm using a geometers definition of frame inappropriately in this context..?

Comment: Sorry I meant $\mathbb{R}^4$. I will edit the problem right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a finite collection of vectors $\mathscr{B}$ in a finite dimensional vectors space $V$, if $\operatorname{span}(\mathscr{B}) = V$, then $\mathscr{B}$ is a frame. If you remove the last column from your matrix, you will notice that the determinant of the resulting matrix is non-zero; this implies the first four columns of the matrix span $\Bbb{R}^4$ which further implies that the five vectors given are a frame. The frame is tight if there exists some $\alpha$ such that for any vector $v \in \Bbb{R}^4$ it happens that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^5 \big| \langle v, e_k\rangle \big|^2 = \alpha \|v\|^2$ where $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^5$ are the five vectors you gave.

Comment: $v_4−v_5=(\frac{1}{2},1,1,1)−(0,0,0,1)=(\frac{1}{2},1,1,0)=v_3$ But the other vectors are linearly independent from each other. Hence it is a frame. How is it a tight frame?

Comment: I've edited to update my answer including how to check if the frame is tight.

Comment: Can you do one example with one of the vectors?