# How to proof frame is tight?

Tags: proof-explanation, change-of-basis

I wonder how to proof that a given set of vectors is a frame and tight.

A nice explanation has been given here before:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/954403

However, I am puzzled about the following sentence:

"The frame is tight if there exists some $\alpha$ such that for any vector $v \in \Bbb{R}^4$ it happens that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^5 \big| \langle v, e_k\rangle \big|^2 = \alpha \|v\|^2$ where $\{e_k\}_{k=1}^5$ are the five vectors you gave."

I understand, that this is necessary to show, but how does one show this for **any** $v \in \Bbb{R}^4$?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you have to do the direct calculation since you are dealing with an equality. So just take $ v=( v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4)$ and start working.

Edit: Consider the following example where $w_1 = (1, 0), w_2 = (-1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)$ and $w_3 = (-1/2, -\sqrt{3}/2)$. Let us show $\{w_1, w_2, w_3\}$ is a tight frame. Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^3_{k=1}|\langle v, w_i\rangle|^2 =&\ |(v_1, v_2)\cdot (1, 0)|^2 + |(v_1, v_2)\cdot(-1/2, \sqrt{3}/2)|^2 + |(v_1, v_2)\cdot(-1/2, -\sqrt{3}/2)|^2\\
=&\ v_1^2+(-v_1/2+\sqrt{3}v_2/2)^2+(-v_1/2-\sqrt{3}v_2/2)^2\\
=&\ v_1^2+\frac{1}{4}v_1^2+\frac{3}{4}v_2^2-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}v_1v_2+\frac{1}{4}v_1^2+\frac{3}{4}v_2^2+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}v_1v_2\\
=&\ \frac{3}{2}v_1^2 + \frac{3}{2}v_2^2 = \frac{3}{2}\|v\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would you mind explaining how one does this in more detail? I am a newbie to mathematics and have never really proven such things. I am not even sure how to start now..

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps. Two questions. 

1) I assume the last step is the Euclidean norm. However, that one is defined as: $sqrt(v_1^2+v_2^2+...)=\|v\|.$

Comment: I hit enter too quickly :-) But what you describe above looks somewhat different than the Euclidean norm, as you have no square root there.

2) (I think this is related) Why is it sufficient to show this for two vectors?

Comment: It's the euclidean norm.

Comment: Sorry, stupid of me, I missed the square.

Comment: I have trouble understanding another line and would be grateful if you can help out! Why is it: \langle v, w_1\rangle|^2 =&\ |(v_1, v_2)\cdot (1, 0)|^2$, and not: $|\langle v, (0,1)\rangle|^2=\|(v)\|^2 \|(1, 0)\|^2 cos{\theta}^2$ where $\theta$ is angle between $v$ and $e_1$?

Comment: Formatting went wrong, again my question more readable: I have trouble understanding another line and would be grateful if you can help out! Why is it: $ |\langle v, (0,1)\rangle|^2 = |(v_1, v_2)\cdot (1, 0)|^2$, and not:
$|\langle v, (0,1)\rangle|^2=\|(v)\|^2 \|(0, 1)\|^2 cos^2{\theta}$ where
$\theta$ is angle between $v$ and $e_1=(0,1)$?

Comment: The vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so the inner product is usually just the dot product, i.e. the sum of the products of the coordinates.